# Design forms in SharePoint Online - custom

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, powerapp

I am designing a form in SharePoint Online, where the form has three kind of users.

1. Requestor – Can create new event from the Create New Request page. Some form fields required to be auto-populated like logged-in user and some form fields need to have auto-complete on, based on previous value entered.
2. Moderator – Can blacklist the event, by clicking on the blacklist button in the form. If the organiser is blacklisted, requestor cannot add-in the same organiser again in the New Request page. It should show alert.
3. Approver -  Should approve the request. All form fields should be set to shaded/read only.

I explored various approaches in designing these forms for SharePoint Online.

4. Using PowerApps and flow – Since the form has lot of customizations, like on button click, should blacklist the event and show alerts. Should show certain fields based on permissions. I am not sure whether this can be done in PowerApps as its usually a no-code solution. Small JavaScript’s I wont be able to execute, unless depending on Spfx framework which is complex.
5. Using InfoPath + SPDesigner – I understand InfoPath is being deprecated in 2026 and shouldn’t be absolutely used in SharePoint Online. But it does offer me some JavaScript customization.
6. Plumsail Forms – I think its doable using Plumsail Forms since it offers form designing + JavaScript’s. Only thing is licenses need to be purchased on yearly basis.

Any technical advice which is the best possible way to design these form to meet the above requirement ? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create these forms in modern SharePoint use the SPFx webpart.  In the SPFx webpart, use no javascript framework.  Inside the webpart add jquery.  After this, you should be able to create highly customized forms.

Answer (score 0):

PowerApps will get you most or all of the way there. It certainly supports conditional visibility of fields. If you need more flexibility and want access to javascript, then user2353634 has a good suggestion of SPFx. Since you'd still be posting to a SharePoint list, you'd still have access to flow.

edit: I forgot to add my standard powerapps disclaimer - while powerapps might indeed work, it's a difficult tool to learn and to work with, far more difficult than the advertising suggests.

Answer (score -2):

Based on my research, I recommend your approach using InfoPath and SharePoint designer.

The ability to add events to the blacklist is similar to preventing users from submitting requests repeatedly.

This aspect you can refer to the following link:

https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/30158/104689.aspx

As for the mail reminder you can set up in SharePoint designer.